How to use $host in path to SSL certificate in NGINX
I have 2 certificates, one for domain foo.com and another for bar.com
No I would like to serve both from one server definition
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name foo.com bar.com;

    ssl_certificate     $cert_path/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key $cert_path/privkey.pem;
}

Inside the http { .. }  I have the $cert_path defined
map $host $cert_path {
  foo.com      /etc/certbot/live/foo.org;
  bar.com      /etc/certbot/live/bar.org;
}

I keep getting log errors like this
 2024/10/04 11:30:13 [error] 9#9: *73 cannot load certificate "/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling fopen(/fullchain.pem, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file) while SSL handshaking, client: x.x.x.x, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Somehow the trick with the map and trying to load the certificate based on the $host-name doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions what might go wrong here?

The $host variable is calculated from three sources, including the headers in the http request.
ssl_certificate is processed before the secure connection is established, so before any http headers have been received by the server.
The manual page gives examples using $ssl_server_name which is the server name requested through SNI.
You should be able to use $ssl_server_name instead of $host in your map statement.
Note: If your Nginx service runs with reduced privileges, you may need to change the permissions of the /etc/certbot/live directories and files.
